# Camera view to Mat object using EmguCV and Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, emgucv

I need to do some image processing in unity. What only interests me is a view from the camera object. I capture the view by using readPixels32 and getPixels32. Thus i end up with a Color32[] array. How can i create a Mat (matrix from opencv) object? Is there any better way to capture camera view?

Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the Unity side of things, but with EmguCV it's often preferable to use the Image<> object.

http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Working_with_Images#Creating_Image_2

Take a look at the various Image<> Constructors and what sort of transforms you are able to get from what unity provides.

You will likely have to create an Image<> of the right height/width and then loop over it, assigning each pixel explicitly.